# Injector MIA for Mighty Morphin' Quest

Tags: borderlands-2

Sir Hammerlock in Sanctuary has given me the quest "Mighty Morphin,'" this quest requires me to take an item from him that is a serum injector. Then I am supposed to use said injector to inject Varkid cocoons in Tundra Express. However, I can't find the item in my inventory after I grab it from Hammerlock (if it is even a weapon or whatever), and I've no idea how to inject the cocoons with the serum. Am I supposed to have something in my inventory? What am I doing wrong? :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not an item in your inventory. Just 'use' the cocoon when they turn into one.

Comment: Ahh, in the heat of fighting I never saw the push "x" to inject option. Thanks! I feel kinda silly now :)